# Identify missing values in a sequence / perform asymmetric difference between two lists

Tags: r, missing-data

Using R, I want to efficiently identify which values in a sequence are missing. I've written the below example of how I do it. There must be a better way. Can someone help?

```
data.list=c(1,2,4,5,7,8,9)

full.list=seq(from = 1, to = 10, by =1)

output <- c()
for(i in 1:length(full.list)){
    holder1 <- as.numeric(any(data.list == i))
    output[i] <- holder1
}

which(output == 0)
```

Comment: I suggest that you modify the title of the question since missing values in R had another signification...

Comment: @agstudy Could you suggest something?

Comment: For example, How to perform asymmetric difference between 2 lists?:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another possible solution

```
 setdiff(full.list,data.list)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
full.list[!full.list %in% data.list]
```

Comment: It seems like `setdiff()` will not identify a difference if the two sequences are factors, if the underlying factor sets are the same. The `%in%` method, however, identifies differences in the actual sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `match` (similar to `%in%`)

```
full.list[!match(full.list,data.list,nomatch=FALSE)]
[1]  3  6 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep()`:

`grep(paste("^", data.list, "$", sep = "", collapse = "|"), full.list, invert = TRUE)`

You could be "lazy" and use `collapse = ^|$` but use the above for precise accuracy.

Using `grepl()`:

`full.list[!grepl(paste("^", data.list, "$", sep = "", collapse = "|"), full.list)]`